# Generic Single Linked List using std::unique_ptr, unknown uncompilation errors in Microsoft Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linked-list

I am very new to Microsoft visual studio C++ as well as std::unique_ptr. On CodeReview I was recommended to rewrite using std::unique_ptr. You can find the question I am referencing [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195033/creating-a-generic-single-linked-list).

Here are the following errors I am receiving:

```
1>main.cpp
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(26): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(61): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'SingleLinkedList<T>' being compiled
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(65): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(104): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(104): error C7510: 'make_unique': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(120): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(120): error C7510: 'make_unique': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(136): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(136): error C7510: 'make_unique': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(145): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(145): error C7510: 'make_unique': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(152): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(152): error C7510: 'make_unique': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(164): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\singlelinkedlist.h(164): error C7510: 'make_unique': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'
1>Done building project "LinkedList.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef SingleLinkedList_h
#define SingleLinkedList_h

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class SingleLinkedList {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;
        Node(T x) : data(x), next(nullptr) {}
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> tail = nullptr;

    // This function is for the overloaded operator << 
    void display(std::ostream &str) const {
        for (std::make_unique<Node> loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
            str << loop->data << "\t";
        }
        str << "\n";
    }

public:
    // Constructors
    SingleLinkedList() = default;                                           // empty constructor 
    SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList const &source);                       // copy constructor

    // Rule of 5
    SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList &&move) noexcept;                     // move constructor
    SingleLinkedList& operator=(SingleLinkedList &&move) noexcept;          // move assignment operator
    ~SingleLinkedList();                                    

    // Overload operators
    SingleLinkedList& operator=(SingleLinkedList const &rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &str, SingleLinkedList &data) {
        data.display(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Memeber functions
    void swap(SingleLinkedList &other) noexcept;
    void push(const T &theData);                            
    void push(T &&theData);
    void display() const;
    void insertHead(const T &theData);
    void insertTail(const T &theData);
    void insertPosition(int pos, const T &theData);
    void deleteHead();
    void deleteTail();
    void deletePosition(int pos);
    bool search(const T &x);
};

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList<T> const &source) {
    for(std::make_unique<Node> loop = source->head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        push(loop->data);
    }
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList<T>&& move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>& SingleLinkedList<T>::operator=(SingleLinkedList<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::~SingleLinkedList() {
    while (head != nullptr) {
        deleteHead();
    }
}

template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>& SingleLinkedList<T>::operator=(SingleLinkedList const &rhs) {
    SingleLinkedList copy{ rhs };
    swap(copy);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::swap(SingleLinkedList &other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(head, other.head);
    swap(tail, other.tail);
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::push(const T &theData) {
    std::make_unique<Node> newNode = Node(theData);

    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        newNode = nullptr;
    }

    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::push(T &&theData) {
    std::make_unique<Node> newNode = Node(std::move(theData));

    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        newNode = nullptr;
    }

    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::display() const {
    std::make_unique<Node> newNode = head;
    while (newNode != nullptr) {
        std::cout << newNode->data << "\t";
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::insertHead(const T &theData) {
    std::make_unique<Node> newNode = Node(theData);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::insertTail(const T &theData) {
    std::make_unique<Node> newNode = Node(theData);
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T &theData) {

}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::deleteHead() {
    std::make_unique<Node> old = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete old;
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::deleteTail() {

}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::deletePosition(int pos) {

}

template <class T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::search(const T &x) {

}




#endif /* SingleLinkedList_h*/
```

Here is the main.cpp file:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include "SingleLinkedList.h"


    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////// Single Linked List //////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        SingleLinkedList<int> obj;
        obj.push(2);
        obj.push(4);
        obj.push(6);
        obj.push(8);
        obj.push(10);
        std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout<<"---------------displaying all nodes---------------";
        std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << obj << std::endl;

        //
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    std::cout<<"-----------------Inserting At End-----------------";
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    obj.insertTail(20);
        //    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
        //
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    std::cout<<"----------------Inserting At Start----------------";
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    obj.insertHead(50);
        //    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
        //
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    std::cout<<"-------------Inserting At Particular--------------";
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    obj.insertPosition(5,60);
        //    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
        //
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting At Start-----------------";
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    obj.deleteHead();
        //    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
        //
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting At End-----------------";
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    obj.deleteTail();
        //    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
        //
        //
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    std::cout<<"--------------Deleting At Particular--------------";
        //    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        //    obj.deletePosition(4);
        //    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
        //    std::cout << std::endl;
        //
        //    obj.search(8) ? printf("Yes"):printf("No");







        std::cin.get();
}
```

I assume most of the errors are syntax errors or that I just made very careless mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you `#include <iostream>` in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk of your syntax errors are derivatives of the same mistake, so lets look at the first one. It's extra-instructive because it points out TWO mistakes. Any time you can kill two stones with one bird, I say go for it. It's damn hard to kill a stone at the best of times.

```
void display(std::ostream &str) const {
    for (std::make_unique<Node> loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}
```

In `std::make_unique<Node> loop = head`, `std::make_unique`is a function that gives you a `std::unique_ptr`. It is not a type you can use to declare a variable. This mistake is repeated several times through the code and cleaning up all of them will reveal a bunch of new errors. Yay fun.

Step one, let's replace the function with the correct type.

```
void display(std::ostream &str) const {
    for (std::unique_ptr<Node> loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}
```

Groovy. Simple. Unfortunately it doesn't work. `std::unique_ptr<Node> loop = head` means you now have two `unique_ptr`s to the same object. That doesn't sound particularly unique and the compiler won't allow it. You'll probably get some arcane error message about a deleted function. That's because `unique_ptr`'s copy constructor and `=` operator have been banished to the dark dimension to make it harder to accidentally wind up with multiple `unique_ptr`s.

A quick note on why all this matters: Ownership. One of the biggest problems with pointers is deciding who `delete`s what and when. To sort this out you establish ownership of a pointer. Perhaps the pointer is to an Automatic variable and the stack or whatever's being used to manage Automatic data will take care of it. You `delete` NOTHING! Muhuhahahaha! Maybe someone `new`ed the variable. Someone has to `delete` it. That someone is the owner. Some insane fool may even have `malloc`ed the object. Someone has to `free` it instead of `delete`ing it. Again, that's the owner.

There is no practical way to determine how the object was allocated and how it needs to be disposed of from a pointer. All a pointer does is point. The programmer needs to establish a contract that outlines who, if anybody, looks after it and how. In the old days this could be a painstaking process.

History has shown that contract-based pointer management is difficult to get right. And if you do get it right, the next programmer to come along can completely smurf it up. Pointer management works a lot better when the contract has some sort of automated enforcement.

Today we use a smart pointer. There are a bunch of smart pointers. We're sticking to `unique_ptr` this time. If you want to know more, read [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

`unique_ptr` is the owner. It is a plain old Automatic variable that happens to contain a pointer that it will release as soon as the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope. No more worries about ownership. The owner is explicit. And like the [Highlander, There can be only one.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(film)). If you have two `unique_ptr`s to the same object, it's not all that unique, is it? With two owners, one would go out of scope first and destroy the object, leaving the other owner a ticking timebomb.

Do not `new` a `unique_ptr`. That completely defeats the point.

You cannot copy a `unique_ptr`, but you can transfer ownership with `std::move`. Note that the object, if any, currently owned by the the destination `unique_ptr` will be destroyed.

If you call a function that receives a `unique_ptr`, you will have to transfer ownership to the receiving function parameter. The pointer will now be destroyed the function returns, assuming it doesn't transfer ownership of the pointer elsewhere. Since you often don't want this to happen, but still want the ownership of the pointer to remain clear, pass the `unique_ptr` by reference.

You can also use the `unique_ptr::get` method to get a raw, un-owned pointer, but whoever you give it to must know to leave the pointer alone, and that brings us back to contract- based pointer management.

Huh. That wasn't all that <expletive deleted> quick, was it? Sorry about that.

Getting back on topic, your pointer is owned by a `unique_ptr`. You can't just make a new copy with `std::unique_ptr<Node> loop = head;`, Highlander's law, above. Transferring ownership to a tightly scoped Automatic variable that will die and destroy the pointer at the end of the loop with `std::unique_ptr<Node> loop = std::move(head);` would leave the `head` pointer pointing to nothing. Not useful. The linked list is ruined, but at least everything in it was "correctly" destroyed.

As discussed above you can use a reference or `get`. You cannot reseat the reference with `loop = loop->next`, so reference cannot work. That leaves `get`

```
void display(std::ostream &str) const {
    for (Node* loop = head.get(); loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next.get()) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}
```

There is very little room in which the programmer can get confused by the raw pointer here and ownership is still guaranteed by the `unique_ptr`, so all should be good.

This problem is repeated in

```
template <class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(SingleLinkedList<T> const &source) {
    for(std::make_unique<Node> loop = source->head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        push(loop->data);
    }
}
```

Same solution.

There is a variant in the two `push` methods

```
template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::push(const T &theData) {
    std::make_unique<Node> newNode = Node(theData);

    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        newNode = nullptr;
    }

    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

Solution (sort of):

```
template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::push(const T &theData) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_unique<Node>(theData);

    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        newNode = nullptr;
    }

    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

But note the assignments to `head` and `tail`. That violates Highlander and needs to be fixed. You can transfer ownership of `newNode` into `head`, but then there is nothing left to give `tail`. And why should `tail` get ownership of anything? Whatever `tail` points at should be owned by `head` or some `Node`'s `next`. It's ownership is guaranteed. Since it's confined within `SingleLinkedList` it is entering into a contract with itself and can get away with just being a plain old pointer.

That means

```
Node* tail = nullptr;
```

and

```
template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::push(const T &theData) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_unique<Node>(theData);

    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = std::move(newNode);
        tail = head.get();
    }
    else {
        tail->next = std::move(newNode);
        tail = tail->next.get();
    }
}
```

I'm out of time, but

```
void SingleLinkedList<T>::insertHead(const T &theData)
```

and

```
void SingleLinkedList<T>::insertTail(const T &theData) {
```

need to be updated to the new world order and take into account "What if the list is empty?"

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still have some compilation errors but much fewer then before. I will make a follow up post.